# Debugging Python in Intellij IDEA called from C++

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio-2010, intellij-idea

My C++ application contains Python (2.7.6) code calls. I am using Visual Studio 2010 for C++ debugging and IntelliJ IDEA 13 as Python debugger.

I am looking for a way to stop at break points set in IntelliJ while calling Python from C++ code being debugged in Visual Studio.

Thank you!

Comment: You want breakpoints at specific lines in Python code?

Comment: I would like to set breakpoints in Python code in IntelliJ and stop there calling Python from within C++ being debugged in Visual Studion